# CSS Fixed and Absolute

Tags: html, css

My page has a fixed header, and there are content below. I have a div element, inside which I would like to relatively position another div. So I'm using the following structure:

- Header: Fixed position
- Container div: relative position
- Div inside div: absolute position

This is all looking good, however in practice the relative and the absolute divs are displayed in front of the header, when scrolling.

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
h2{
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I know about z-index, however before using another CSS element, I would like to know if it's possible to solve this problem without adding a new variable to the already existing code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: top: 0; padding-top: as your header height

Comment: Me too. I checked also in a editor and works okey. https://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=e1f4250c3615a702dd021f430d42bd9d

Comment: The above code isn't working as it displays both the divs in front of the header. Which is the actually issue the OP did describe in his question. He asked for a way to get the header on top, which most answers did supply. So stop replying to all the answers that they are faulty.

Comment: Only the relative and the absolute divs are in front of my header. My browsers are outdated (company-restrictions), both in Firefox and Chrome it is the same. FF version: 52.9.0, Chrome version: 68.0.3440.75. Although I just checked IE, and it works there properly, so I think only our company Chrome and FF are outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you:

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  z-index: 0;
}

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

h2 {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <h2>FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER</h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

  <div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
    <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have just added `z-index: 0;` to `div.relative` and `z-index: 9;` to `h2`[*the `z-index` to the `h2` can be changed as per your requirement, **it works as layer format**, so if you want your `h2` to be top of all elements you can even go with `z-index: 9999;`, but all this depends upon the other elements in the page.*].

Comment: Thank you, weBBer! It seems that my FF and Chrome version are outdated, however since this code will be used internally in the company, I can't assume others will have updated browsers (everyone has the same versions), thus z-indexing really does need to be applied.

Comment: @CAJ69I My browsers are up to date you problem was there in it. DomenikReitzne has not looked it properly I think.

Comment: My mistake... the green line was pretty hard to see... :D

Comment: @DomenikReitzner it's K bro,  glad you understand Cheers. :)

Comment: It was my mistake too, I should have used a background color for the divs too.

Answer (score 3):

I believe adding a simple `z-index: 1` to the header is the way to go.

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
h2{
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use   `z-index: 1;` into your `Fixed` `header` will solved the problem.

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
h2{
position: fixed;
background-color: yellow;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DomenikReitzner can you plz observe carefully the div's by scrolling down , it's gets over the header

Answer (score 2):

Use **z-index**

```
h2{
   z-index:2;
  }
```

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
 
}
h2{
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;
top:0px;
z-index:2;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER FIXED HEADER</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a position to an element takes it out of the normal flow of the page. Which can cause them to overlap each other. The only way to make sure to the elements are displayed in the right order on the z-axis is with the `z-index` property in css.

```
h2{
   position: fixed;
   background-color: white;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Should be enough to fix your issues.

Answer (score 1):

z-index is the most obvious and easiest way. Set the z-index to a high number like 9999 -  `z-index:9999`. This will bring the header to the top most layer.

Comment: I'll stick to the z-indexing, thank you for your answer!